# HasMany with pluck - does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

My Model:

```
public function colors(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductMeta')->where('type', 'content')->where('key', 'color');
}
```

My Controller:

```
$watchlist_products = Product::whereIn('id', $watchlist_ids)->colors->pluck('value')->toArray();
```

It returns:

```
Property [colors] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

I can not return colors with any of that? Whats wrong with that?

Comment: use `colors()` instead of `colors`

Comment: when using a function a ```whereIn```function it will give you collection. So you cannot run ```colors``` method from ```Product``` model under ```Collection``` class

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: `whereIn` does not return a Collection, it is a Query Builder method, it returns the Query Builder ... this error does not match up to your code above

Answer (score 0):

Because `Product::whereIn('id', $watchlist_ids)` return more than one product, you can not call `->colors()` method on it. the question is `colors of which product?`

You can get the above result in different ways

For example one way is:

```
$result = ProductMeta::whereIn('product_id', $watchlist_ids)
->where('type', 'content')
->where('key', 'color')
->pluck('value')
->toArray();
```

Another way is `eager loading` the colors on product collection and using `dot notation` in the `->pluck()` method

```
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $watchlist_ids)->with('colors')->get();
$result = $products->pluck('colors.*.value')->flatten()->toArray();
```